# Check values in columns, allowing for not all columns being present

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clean up raw data exported from an online database.

There can be up to five columns. If all cells in a row have a value of 0, I want to delete that row.

When the user exports the data, they can choose to exclude columns, and the columns can be in any order.

For example, if the data contains only two of the possible five columns, I want to check just those two for 0s.

Comment: You can use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` to test if the column is present or not by finding the header.

Comment: 1. When user exports data there might be more than those 5 columns with quantitative data?

2.You have no idea about the order of the columns -> they will be just somewhere in the sheet?

Comment: @BigBen, so would you suggest just using a super long nested If, where I first check the presence of column 1, then check the value, then check the presence of column 2, etc, etc... and set a boolean to True if all present columns are 0?  Or can you think of a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

Could do a a big loop looking at every row and seeing if all 5 columns in that row are blank

```
Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname")
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

For i = 1 To LastRow
If (sh.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And sh.Cells(i, 2).Value = "" And sh.Cells(i, 3).Value = "" And _
sh.Cells(i, 4).Value = "" And sh.Cells(i, 5).Value = "") Then
sh.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
i = i - 1
Dim newLastRow As Integer
newLastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
If i = newLastRow Then
Exit For
End If
End If
Next i
MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@kyle campbell, thank you for your input!  It didn't quite get me there, but it did get my wheels turning.  Here is the solution I came up with, if anyone's curious:

I set a variable to represent the column number for each of the 5 possible columns using Range.Find.  If the Find came up with nothing, I set the variable to 49, since the maximum number of columns this report can have is 48.

Then I did a nested If to test if the value in each cell was either 0 or null (because if the column number is 49, there won't be any data there).  If all Ifs were true, I deleted the row.  I also added a counter and message box, just to make sure this worked.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim O As Long
Dim E As Long
Dim H As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim P As Long

lRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

If Range("1:1").Find("SUM(OBLIGATIONS)") Is Nothing Then
    O = 49
Else
    O = Range("1:1").Find("SUM(OBLIGATIONS)").Column
End If

If Range("1:1").Find("SUM(EXPENDITURES)") Is Nothing Then
    E = 49
Else
    E = Range("1:1").Find("SUM(EXPENDITURES)").Column
End If

If Range("1:1").Find("SUM(HOURS)") Is Nothing Then
    H = 49
Else
    H = Range("1:1").Find("SUM(HOURS)").Column
End If

If Range("1:1").Find("SUM(BUDGET_RESOURCES)") Is Nothing Then
    B = 49
Else
    B = Range("1:1").Find("SUM(BUDGET_RESOURCES)").Column
End If

If Range("1:1").Find("SUM(PRIOR_YEAR_RECOVERY)") Is Nothing Then
    P = 49
Else
    P = Range("1:1").Find("SUM(PRIOR_YEAR_RECOVERY)").Column
End If

Dim j As Integer
j = 0

For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, O) = 0 Or Cells(i, O) = "" Then
        If Cells(i, E) = 0 Or Cells(i, E) = "" Then
            If Cells(i, H) = 0 Or Cells(i, H) = "" Then
                If Cells(i, B) = 0 Or Cells(i, B) = "" Then
                    If Cells(i, P) = 0 Or Cells(i, P) = "" Then
                        Rows(i).Delete
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Macro complete, " & j & " lines deleted."

End Sub
```